# What does .userData([android:"true"]) convey in ktlint('0.43.2').userData([android: "true"])

Tags: android, gradle, lint, ktlint, spotless

```
ktlint('0.43.2').userData([android: "true"])
```

is a statement in `spotless.gralde` on using spotless with `ktlint`. I would like to know what is being conveyed when we give `android:"true"` in `userData`.

```
kotlin {
    target '**/*.kt'
    trimTrailingWhitespace()
    indentWithSpaces()
    endWithNewline()
    targetExclude("$buildDir/**/*.kt")
    targetExclude('bin/**/*.kt')

    ktlint('0.43.2')
            .userData([android: "true"])
}
```